# Autostart services in System V system

Tags: services, sysvinit, autostart

In systemD, we need to execute this command to autostart an application on system startup: `sudo systemctl enable <service-name>`. What will be the equivalent command for sysvinit since chkconfig is no longer supported? I could not find any.

Comment: What is your distribution? If you have SystemV you should have `chkconfig`

Comment: @RomeoNinov, my distribution is MX-Linux. And it does not have `chkconfig`.

Comment: From what I see MX-Linux use systemd, not SysV. So you should use `systemctl`

Comment: @RomeoNinov, by default, MX-Linux uses SystemV. Please check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708174/2908599) in SO you should use not `chkconfig`, but `update-rc.d`:

```
update-rc.d <service> defaults
update-rc.d <service> start 20 3 4 5
update-rc.d -f <service>  remove
```

Comment: I did not get the second command mentioned here. How to enable autostart of a service using `update-rc.d`?

Comment: @lonewolf, standard or created by you?

Comment: standard services.

Comment: In such case `update-rc.d <service> defaults` should set the default runlevels for a service and `update-rc.d <service> enable` (or `start`) should start it